# When I click on a radio button the checked attribute doesn't change

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So I have this bit of code and I want it to change its selected attribute when I click on the other radio button.

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend class="h4">Formati:</legend>
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="version_printimi" value="A4">A4
  </label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="version_printimi" value="Skontrino" checked="checked">Skontrino
  </label>
</fieldset>
```

They are inside a form and visually the radiobuttons do get changed but I need the changed attribute to change as well.

Comment: Hard to call the above *"code"*. That's markup syntax. What's missing in your example is JavaScript code.

Comment: The checked _attribute_ won't change but the checked _property_ will. Why do you need the _attribute_ to change? Sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info).

Comment: The only question is, WHY do you want the attribute to change? Grabbing the input and looking at its `.checked` will work fine. HTML code is just the initial state of the DOM, everything else happens "in the ether" if you will (the RAM of your machine). Don't waste time trying to get HTML to "look right", focus on solving the actual problem.

Comment: If you need this for a selector or css, then there are other ways, namely [`:checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `onchange` event listener to both of the input tags to detect change, then call a function that adds an attribute to one of the radio inputs using `setAttribute` and remove an attribute from other radio using `removeAttribute`.